# Securing doorkeeper with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I need to lock /oath/application and added this to my doorkeeper initializer

```
admin_authenticator do
  redirect_to(root_url) unless session["warden.user.user.key"]
    if session["warden.user.user.key"]
      current_user = User.find_by_id(session["warden.user.user.key"][0][0])
      if current_user
        current_user.admin? || redirect_to(root_url)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I don't think that this is very secure since one could just create a cookie and test every User id. My question is this: Is there a better way inside an initializer file to determine whether a user is really logged in when using devise for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is available, and you don't need the `User.find_by_id(session["warden.user.user.key"][0][0])` call.